# Many to many relationship mapping in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with many to many relationship in EF core.
I have the following model classes:

```
public class Meal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Insulin { get; set; }
    public MealType Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MealFood> MealFoods { get; set; }

    public Meal()
    {
        MealFoods = new Collection<MealFood>();
    }
}

public class Food
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Carbohydrates { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MealFood> MealFoods { get; set; }

    public Food()
    {
        MealFoods = new Collection<MealFood>();
    }
}

public class MealFood
{
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public Food Food { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following API resource class:

```
public class MealResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Insulin { get; set; }
    public MealType Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FoodResource> Foods { get; set; }

    public MealResource()
    {
        Foods = new Collection<FoodResource>();
    }
}
```

I have done the mapping in my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MealFood>().HasKey(mf => new { mf.MealId, mf.FoodId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<MealFood>().HasOne(mf => mf.Meal).WithMany(m => m.MealFoods).HasForeignKey(mf => mf.MealId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MealFood>().HasOne(mf => mf.Food).WithMany(f => f.MealFoods).HasForeignKey(mf => mf.FoodId);
    }
```

I've got a problem with this call:

```
var meals = await context.Meals.Include(m => m.MealFoods).ToListAsync();
```

[This returns almost everything I need, except the navigation properties from MealFoods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqT77.png)

The reason why I want those properties, because I want to do the following mapping:

```
CreateMap<Meal, MealResource>().ForMember(mr => mr.Foods, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.MealFoods.Select(y => y.Food).ToList()));
```

I have already found this:
[Automapper many to many mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407392/automapper-many-to-many-mapping)

but (maybe I don't get something) this doesn't work because the property called Food in MealFood is null.

I hope I didn't explain too complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include navigation property, EF Core automatically fills the inverse navigation property, e.g. including `Meal.MealFoods` will automatically fill `MealFood.Meal`, including `Food.MealFoods` will automatically populate `MealFood.Food` etc. In order to populate other navigation properties you need to use additional `ThenInclude`. E.g.

```
var meals = await context.Meals
    .Include(m => m.MealFoods)
        .ThenInclude(mf => mf.Food) // <--
    .ToListAsync();
```

or

```
var foods = await context.Foods
    .Include(f => f.MealFoods)
        .ThenInclude(mf => mf.Meal) // <--
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yes! This is the one, it works! Thank you very much!