# Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API.Entities.CompanySetting]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, api, automapper

I am trying to find a simple way using AutoMapper to return all companies that are linked to a specific User Id in a many-to-many relationship scenario.  I followed the SO [Automapper many to many mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407392/automapper-many-to-many-mapping) but I get the error message "Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API.Entities.CompanySetting]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable" when trying to follow the logic.

My AppUser entity:

```
public class AppUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySetting> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; }  = new List<AppUserCompanySetting>();
      
    }
```

My CompanySetting entity:

```
public class CompanySetting
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public bool isArchived { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AppUserCompanySetting> AppUserCompanySettings { get; set; } = new List<AppUserCompanySetting>();
    }
```

And I have the Join table

```
public class AppUserCompanySetting
    {
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int CompanySettingsId { get; set; }
        public virtual CompanySetting CompanySettings { get; set; }
    }
```

I then created a CompanySettingDto

```
public class CompanySettingDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public bool isArchived { get; set; }

    }
```

And a MemberDto:

```
public class MemberDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string KnownAs { get; set; }
        public int TimeActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActive {get; set;}
        public ICollection<PhotoDto> Photos { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CompanySettingDto> CompanyInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

I then tried Automapper to bring the relationships between the User and the Company Information I require:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyInformation, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.AppUserCompanySettings.Select(y => y.CompanySettings).ToList()))
            CreateMap<CompanySetting, CompanySettingDto>();
        }
    }
```

I am writing an API call to get all companies that are linked to a specific UserId.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MemberDto>> GetCompaniesByUserIdAsync(int userId)
        {
            return await _context.Users
                .Where(x => x.Id == userId)
                .ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it likes your initializers. (new list)

Comment: @Nikki9696 I tried removing the initializers before posting.  That did not resolve the issue.