# Updating many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I have three tables to denote many to many relationships. The models are shown here:

```
public class Feature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    //Navigation Properties  
    public List<Menu> Menus { get; } = new();
    public List<FeatureMenu> FeatureMenus { get; } = new();
}

public class Menu
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Navigation Properties
    public List<Feature> Features { get; } = new();        
    public List<FeatureMenu> FeatureMenus { get; } = new();
}

[Table("FeatureMenus")]
public class FeatureMenu
{        
    public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }     
    public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    //Navigation Properties
    public Feature Feature { get; set; } = null!;
    public Menu Menu { get; set; } = null!;    
}
```

I am using this `Add` method to add a menu and any `Features` the menu may belong to:

```
public async Task<Menu> CreateAsync(List<Guid> featuresId, Menu menu)
{
    foreach(var featureId in featuresId)
    {
        var feature = await db.Features.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == featureId);

        if (feature != null)
        {
            menu.Features.Add(feature);
        }
    }

    await db.Menus.AddAsync(menu);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return menu;
}
```

This code works and the data is inserted into `Menu` as well as the join table `FeatureMenu`.

**Question #1:** is this the most efficient way of adding into parent and child/join table?

**Question #2:** is related to updating `Menu` and `FeatureMenu` entities. I am using below code to update the `Menu` table, however, I am stuck on how to add or remove entries from `FeatureMenu` table based on the `List<Guid> FeaturesId` parameter passed to the `UpdateAsync` method. A client application may add or remove entries from `FeaturesId` when conducting an update.

```
public async Task<Menu?> UpdateAsync(Guid id, List<Guid> FeaturesId, Menu menu)
{
    var existingMenu = await db.Menus.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if (existingMenu == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    menu.Id = id;
    mapper.Map(menu, existingMenu);
    
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return existingMenu;
}
```

Comment: Hi @learner, for add entities, your `CreateAsync` work for this, what do you mean? How do you delete the entities?

Comment: Yes, add is working so that's good. Regarding your question, say a menu belongs to two features (A and B). User updates menu adds feature C, removes Feature B, and calls our update method in a single call. The list featureIds will contain Ids of A and C, it will not contain Id of B. So in this case, our update process should update Menu, add Feature C to menu, and remove Feature B from menu.

Comment: There are many questions on add/updating junction table content in many-to-many relationships. Please try to find them.

Comment: I actually [do that manually](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/SongRepository.cs#L236)...

Comment: I was hoping if there is an automated procedure!

Comment: Are you using [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)?

Comment: Yes, I am using AutoMapper.

Comment: If you are using AutoMapper you should let it handle EF enties CRUD. All you have to do at the end is to call  `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` at the end. You do need to configure entity relationships in AutoMapper though.
Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407392/automapper-many-to-many-mapping

Comment: You should have posted details of your AutoMapper config code in the question body. For some reason you decided not to mention it at all ..... And tag automapper as well.